# Multiple TurtleBots in Concert

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, ros

I've been following the steps on the link http://learn.turtlebot.com/2015/02/04/6/

Everything works perfectly until I start editing the `MASTER_URI`. Then the gazebo concert doesn't appear, it shows `UNKNOWN` instead. What should I do?

Thank you!

Comment: What did you set the MASTER_URI value to?

Comment: you mean editing the master URI at http://localhost:11311 as it said ? yes !